# Muitas perguntas, poucas respostas

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, beta, private-beta

nestes primeiros minutos de beta privado, tenho observado uma coisa que me preocupa muito.

Estamos ganhando uma grande quantidade de perguntas rapidamente, o que é bom. Entretanto, temos poucas respostas até o momento, o que é péssimo.

Além disso, a maioria das perguntas têm um teor um tanto superficial até então.

Então, gostaria de recomendar a todos tentar postar algumas respostas. Vamos tentar manter todas as nossas perguntas respondidas, se possível com mais de uma resposta e/ou com resposta aceita. Para cada pergunta que você quiser fazer, procure dar pelo menos uma resposta à pergunta de uma outra pessoa.

E obviamente, responder a sua própria pergunta é perfeitamente válido e desejável.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você já está preocupado? :)

Os primeiro minutos do beta privado me pareceram momentos de êxtase, todo mundo querendo contribuir de alguma forma, e cada um fazendo do jeito que podia.

Temos muito trabalho pela frente, precisamos arrumar as tags, definir padrões dentre inúmeras outras situações, mas que para mim está tão cedo, mas tão cedo, que não devemos nos preocupar com isso agora.

Nem o cache da [Proposta Portuguese Language no Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) está atualizado com as informações que poderíamos levantar algumas estatísticas a respeito do assunto:

[image: proposta]

E se alguém chegar e responder meia dúzia de perguntas nos próximos minutos, a situação se inverte completamente. Logo, a preocupação dos minutos seguintes pode ser exatamente o contrário: "Muitas respostas para poucas perguntas".

Então, sou a favor de deixar as preocupações para quando começar a ter algo que realmente pode se tornar um problema para nós, mas não agora.

Comment: Ok, depois de algumas horas, parece que a situação agora está bem melhor. Possivelmente por causa deste tópico, mas é bom que já temos um site bem ativo logo nas primeiras horas.

Answer (score 7):

Nesse primeiro momento adicionar perguntas é mais importante do que respostas, não estou dizendo para não responder, mas não precisa colocar prioridade nisso agora. Melhor priorizamos em buscar perguntas de qualidade e alimentar o site neste período inicial.